# Cannot query across one-to-many for property NestJS and TypeORM

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have two entities one is `car` and another one is `carAvailability`

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { CarAvailability } from 'src/car-availabilitys/car-availability.entity';

@Entity('cars')
export class Car {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => CarAvailability, (carAvailability) => carAvailability.car, {
    eager: true,
    cascade: true,
  })
  availabilities: CarAvailability[];
}
```

I am trying to add a service that queries and filters cars based on the availabilities. In My Service and tried two ways:

Method 1 with repo functions:

```
async test () {
  const startDateTime = '2012-04-24 02:25:43.511';

  return await this.repo.find({
    relations: ['availabilities'],
    where: {
      availabilities: {
        start_date_time: startDateTime
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Method 2 with query builder:

```
async test () {
  const startDateTime = '2012-04-24 02:25:43.511';

  return this.repo.createQueryBuilder('cars')
    .innerJoin('cars.availabilities', 'car_availabilities')
    .where("cars.availabilities.start_date_time = :startDateTime", { startDateTime })
    .getMany();
}
```

Method 1 error:

```
Error: Cannot query across one-to-many for property availabilities
```

Method 2 error:

```
QueryFailedError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "availabilities"
```

I feel like I am missing something but I am not sure. Have referred both NestJS and TypeORM docs but can't seem to figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Method 2, because you aliased `car.availabilities` as `car_availabilities`, your `where` clause should use the alias name:

```
car_availabilities.start_date_time
```

not:

```
cars.availabilities.start_date_time
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Method 1 repo functions with nested query builder:

```
async test () {
  const startDateTime = '2012-04-24 02:25:43.511';

  return await this.repo.find({
    relations: ['availabilities'],
    where: (qb) => {
      qb.where('availabilities.start_date_time = :startDateTime', {
        startDateTime
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `cascade` from `oneToMany` side and put:

```
{
  cascade: true,
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  onUpdate:'CASCADE'
}
```

on `manyToOne` side.

And if you going to use relations: `['availabilities']` you can remove `eager: true`.

Answer (score -2):

bro add a .then() after the async function like in my code

```
return await this.repository.find({relations: ['availabilities'])
.then((cars) => cars.filter((car) => car.start_date_time === startDateTime));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not a preferred method because you are doing the filtering in code instead of in SQL (not very efficient). This method always returns all results and then loops thru them to filter the ones you want.

Comment: You're right but this is the only solution i could find