# TypeORM Cannot query across one-to-many for property error

Tags: typeorm

I have the following two entities:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToOne } from "typeorm";

import { Activity } from "./";

@Entity()
export class Fare {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({unique: false,nullable: false})
    name: string;

    @Column({type: "float",unique: false,nullable: false})
    price: number;
    
    @ManyToOne(() => Activity, activity => activity.fares)
    activity: Activity;

    constructor(data ?: Partial<Fare>) {
        Object.assign(this,data);
    }
}
```

and

```
import { Entity, Column, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

import { Fare } from "./";

@Entity()
export class Activity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({unique: true,nullable: false})
    name: string;

    @Column({unique: false,nullable: true})
    description: string;
    
    @OneToMany(() => Fare, (fare) => fare.activity, {cascade: true})
    fares: Fare[];

    constructor(data ?: Partial<Activity>){
        Object.assign(this,data);
    }
}
```

and I want to update an activity using the following body:

```
{"id":10, "name":"dddd", "fares":[{"id":5,"name":"jeune","price":20.0}]}
```

To do so, I implemented the following service:

```
import { singleton } from 'tsyringe'
import { getConnection, Timestamp } from 'typeorm';

import { Activity } from '../entities/';
import { ActivityRepository } from '../repositories'

import { Fare } from '../entities'

@singleton()
export class ActivityService {

    constructor(private _activityRepository: ActivityRepository) {
        this._activityRepository = getConnection("lasso").getCustomRepository(ActivityRepository);
    }
            
    public update = async (activity: Activity, id: number) => {
        const updatedActivity = await this._activityRepository
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .update(Activity)
            .set(activity)
            .where("id = :id", { id: id })
            .execute();
        return updatedActivity;
    }
};
```

When running my update request I get the following error:

```
(node:204854) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot query across one-to-many for property fares
```

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69471840/cannot-query-across-one-to-many-for-property-nestjs-and-typeorm) which seemed related but unfortunately it did not help. Would you know how to solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using `save` method from `Repository` class which according to the documentation
saves all given entities in the database. If entities do not exist in the database then inserts, otherwise updates. This give the following code for my service:

```
import { singleton } from 'tsyringe'
import { getConnection, Timestamp } from 'typeorm';

import { Activity } from '../entities/';
import { ActivityRepository } from '../repositories'

import { Fare } from '../entities'

@singleton()
export class ActivityService {

    constructor(private _activityRepository: ActivityRepository) {
        this._activityRepository = getConnection("lasso").getCustomRepository(ActivityRepository);
    }
            
    public update = async (activity: Activity, id: number) => {
        const updatedActivity = await this._activityRepository.save(activity);
        return updatedActivity;
    }
};
```